# Cordova: how to parse multiple onSuccess values to a function

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, geolocation

I am working on a html/js script with three onSuccess routines from `navigator.compass.watchHeading`, `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` and `navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration`.

I want to parse all three onSuccess values like `positionLat = position.coords.latitude;` etc. to another function for further action when one of them changes.

What is the best/fast way to accomplice this? Is it possible to call the same function from all three without distress the script? How to parse the other values to the function if one calls it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the same success and error callbacks for all 3 calls:

#### Simple way

```
var watchIdAcceleration = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess,
                                              onError,
                                              accelerationOptions);
var watchIdPosition = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,
                                              onError,
                                              geolocationOptions);
 //...
```

In `onSuccess` you get different object structure so its easy to identify from where did you get it:

```
function onSuccess(obj) {
    if(obj.coords !== undefined){/* ... */}            //position
    else if(obj.x !== undefined){/* ... */}                 //acceleration
    else if(obj.magneticHeading !== undefined) {/* ... */}  //compass
 }
```

---

#### Return type way

But I believe this way will be more clear:

```
var watchIdAcceleration = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(
          function(data){
             onSuccess("accelerometer", data);
          }, onError, accelerationOptions);

var watchIdPosition = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
          function(data){
             onSuccess("geolocation", data);
          },onError,geolocationOptions);
 //...
```

So in `onSuccess` callback we can use `switch` by type:

```
function onSuccess(type, obj) {
    switch (type) {                             
       case "geolocation":
          // obj.magneticHeading
       break;
       case "accelerometer":
          //...
       break;
        default:
          //.. not supported

    }
 }
```

Comment: OK, thanks, so when I only want to run the function when all three are successful, something like if(obj.coords !== undefined && obj.x !== undefined && obj.magneticHeading !== undefined) {/* ... */} (from your first answer) should be the solution?

Comment: @Harry not at all. every subscription returns his own data in different time. They don't come all at once but randomly. If you want to catch all in one callback, I would use `Promise.all`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all